# When the critical points of a multivariate polynomial are isolated?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, systems-of-equations

Suppose $f:\mathbb{C}^n\to \mathbb{C}$ is a polynomial of degree $k$. Let $S=\{(z_1,...,z_n)\in \mathbb{C}^n: Df=0\}$, where $Df=(f'_{z_1},...,f'_{z_n})$ is the gradient. My question is: when $S$ has only isolated points?

Maybe this question is related to the [Bézout's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem/%22B%C3%A9zout%27s%20theorem%22). Then do we have the following fact: if $gcd(f'_{z_1},...,f'_{z_n})$=constant, then $S$ has only isolated points? Here $gcd$ means the greatest common divisor of these multivariate polynomials. I don't know whether I understand the theorem correctly. Any help will be appreciated.

P.S. As pointed out by Mohan in the comments, the $gcd$ condition does not lead to the fact that $S$ has only isolated points. What if we add an assumption that $deg_{z_1}(f)=...=deg_{z_n}(f)=deg(f)=k$? Here $deg_{z_j}(f)$ means the highest degree of $z_j$ in $f$.

P.S. I realized that the answer is still no with the assumption above. An example is $f(x,y,z)=\frac29x^3+3y^3+z^3-x^2y$. $S$ contains a line $x=3y,z=0$

P.S. But what if we assume that $gcd(f'_{z_i},f'_{z_j})=constant$, for each pair of $(i,j), i\ne j$?

P.S. I realized that the answer is still no. An example is $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+xyz$. $S$ contains a line $x=y=0$.

Comment: The answer is no, the gcd does not guarantee that. For example, take $f:\mathbb{C}^3\to \mathbb{C}$, $f(x,y,z)=x^2-y^3$. Then, the gcd is constant, since $x,y$ are relatively prime. But, all points $(0,0,t)$ are critical.

Comment: @Mohan Thanks! But are there any conditions imply the fact that $S$ has only isolated points?

Comment: None in such generality.

Comment: @Mohan What if we add an assumption that $deg_{z_1}(f)=...=deg_{z_n}(f)=k$? Here $deg_{z_j}(f)$ means the highest degree of $z_j$ in $f$.

Comment: None of those will work. The only time gcd helps is when $n=2$.

Comment: Remark that $S$ is an algebraic set defined by the ideal $I=\left< f'_{z_1},\dots,f'_{z_n} \right>$. The set $S$ is finite if and only if the algebra $\mathbb{C}[z_1, \dots z_n]/I$ is finite dimensional over $\mathbb{C}$.